# Combining year and month into a same column

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I combine year and month into a one column with format `YYYYMM`? My data doesn't have leading zeros. Below are example columns.

| Year | Month |
| --- | --- |
| 2019 | 7 |
| 2019 | 10 |
| 2020 | 11 |
| 2020 | 3 |
| 2021 | 1 |

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS you're using, as answers may vary slightly between each.

Comment: I've edited your question to make your sample data more legible, please also tag the DBMS you are using.

Comment: Please also include what you've tried so far in an attempt to satisfy the requirement described, along with a short explanation of where *specifically* in that attempt you're getting stuck.

Answer (score 1):

In most RDBMS platforms, you can `CONCAT` both values, while using a bit of string manipulation trickery on the Month field to get it to conform to the format by adding a leading `0` in the event of a single-digit month value:

```
SELECT CONCAT(Year, RIGHT(CONCAT('0', Month), 2) AS YearMonth FROM Dates
```

| YearMonth |
| --- |
| 201907 |
| 201910 |
| 202011 |
| 202003 |
| 202101 |

[<sup>db<>fiddle.uk</sup>](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=889e8b0d73a36f424102435aa087d58c)

Comment: Hello! thanks for the comment. I am using Oracle and it seems that the RIGHT doesn't work. Instead I went with CONCAT(Year, substr(CONCAT('0', Month), 2). 

But still something isn't right. As I try to filter them by >201907 I don't e see values that have a zero in front of the month. For example 202004.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine them as a number:

```
year * 100 + month
```

If you want a string, you can convert this to a string:

```
cast(year * 100 + month as char(6))
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you put it, concatenation along with the `LPAD` function might be what you're looking for. See line #8.

```
SQL> with test (year, month) as
  2    (select 2019,  7 from dual union all
  3     select 2019, 10 from dual union all
  4     select 2020, 11 from dual union all
  5     select 2020,  3 from dual
  6    )
  7  select year, month,
  8         year || lpad(month, 2, '0') result
  9  from test;

      YEAR      MONTH RESULT
---------- ---------- ----------------------------------
      2019          7 201907
      2019         10 201910
      2020         11 202011
      2020          3 202003

SQL>
```